# How to save formatted textarea text to MySQL and load it again?

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have a page where a user can type in a textarea. When a button is pressed, the contents of the textarea are posted to PHP and then saved in a MySQL table. However, when I load it in again any formatting has been removed such as line breaks. For example, suppose this is typed into the textarea:

```
Bob

43

Colorado, USA
```

When it is loaded back it will display like this:

```
Bob 43 Colorado, USA
```

I don't want the user to type any HTML into the textarea but I do want line break formatting to be saved, is there a way I can do this?

Comment: `nl2br` or display in `<pre>` tags.

Comment: I would suggest using a rich text editor instead of a plain text area, use something like tinymce, it will generate HTML for what the user types but won't show HTML (Unless the user wants to see it). Then it will submit the html and you can save that in your database.

Answer (score 0):

You can either use [nl2br](http://php.net/manual/en/function.nl2br.php) or use `<pre></pre>` tags.

nl2br example:

```
echo nl2br("Bob\r\n43\n\rColorado, USA");
```